# Build Variants and different AppIcons

Tags: android-studio, icons, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

I have 2 apps using the same images and resources except the AppIcon.
A common solution for this is having a seperate folder for each app under src and configuring gradle to use the corresponding folder.

In my case 99% of the resources are used from both apps, but only the appicon is different.

Do I have to still use the mechanism of having different res folders or is there also an easier way, so I do not have to clone all the resources ?

I thought I could do something like this:
I have a AndroidManifest Entry as follow :

```
<application android:name="bla.bla.MyApplication" android:largeHeap="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

I can overwrite the name in gradle as follow, which works fine:

```
demo {
    resValue "string", "app_name", "This is the Demo"
    resValue "drawable", "icon", "demoicon"
}
```

Is there a way to overwrite the iconname in the same way ?

As you can see in the snippet above, I already tried, but I get an
Duplicate resources error, because my demoicon saved under res/drawable is generated automatically .

Answer (score 3):

Isolved it the following way:

I did not want to clone the res folder for different build types, only to change the app-icon.

It can be done with manifestPlaceholders:

In my build.gradle :

```
buildTypes {
demo {

            manifestPlaceholders = [iconpath:"@drawable/icon_timeline_test"]
        }
```

it will replace the icon in the AndroidManifest, when referenced as follow:

```
 android:icon="${iconpath}"
```

Answer (score 0):

**If your flavours name like production then:**

```
android.sourceSets.production 
{
    res.srcDirs = ['res', '/path/to/production/res/dir']
}
```

And then in your /path/to/production/res/dir/drawable-* you would have your launcher icon.

Comment: But then I have to clonne the hole res resources from test folder to production folder and I will have to folders with lots of resources doubled, right ? I would like to share all the other stuff except the icon.